# There is a static method named "forClass" in class "DetachedCriteria",but I cannot use it

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm learning spring and hibernate,I use IDEA to edit my project which says Cannot resolve symbol 'forClass' in "DetachedCriteria criteria = new DetachedCriteria.forClass(user.class);"。

I use Spring 5 and Hibernate 5, I tried to Lnvalidate catches and check my dependency，but it is no use。But i find the method in its source code;

this is part of my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.16.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is where I use it:

```
    ApplicationContext applicationContext=(ApplicationContext) this.getServletContext().getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
    userDao ud = (userDao) applicationContext.getBean("userDao");
    **DetachedCriteria criteria = new DetachedCriteria.forClass(user.class);**
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name",a));
    int id  = 0;
    List<?> l = ud.getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: * new DetachedCriteria.forClass(user.class);** ?? either `forClass` or `new` not both.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a method instead of a constructor, so you don't need `new`.

Additionally you should use User.class or user.getClass() if you're doing so on a variable.

Try the following.

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class);
```

Comment: Forgive me ,I'm a fool.Thank you very much.